# i made Jquery ajax call to c# webservice method which return type is void ,while call response goes to error?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I made Jquery ajax call to **c# web service** method which return type is **void**,  while call response goes to error, instead of success.
What is the solution

Here is the code,

**Jquery ajax call :**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "~/MyWebService.asmx/SCheduleDetailsGet",
        data: Data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //async: false,
        //global: false,
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
        },
        error: function (data, xhr, error) {
            debugger;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**C# web service method:**

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
        public void SCheduleDetailsGet(int LoginUserID,int ResumeSearchId,string Flag)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = RHSCheduleGet(LoginUserID, ResumeSearchId, Flag);
                object _jsonReturn = null;
                object jSonString = null;
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
                        new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                _jsonReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
                    _jsonReturn = "{\"aaData\":" + _jsonReturn + "}";
                Context.Response.Write(_jsonReturn);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Context.Response.Write("-2");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If anyone could  help please answer for void return type method

Comment: Please load Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab). Please include the request headers and payload, and the response headers and payload, in your question.

Comment: What do you think `Context.Response.Write` does?